# Deleting while iterating in java! but deleting other then the current object

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

`iterator.remove().` is good however my question: if I want while to iterate, for a kind of condition, to delete another object from the array List.

Example (al being the arraylist)

```
  for (Iterator i = al.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
 IEvent event =(IEvent) i.next();
   if (nbSendingWTS > 0 || nbSendingCTS > 0){
                    i.remove();
                    al.remove(swtsee);
                    al.remove(sdctsee);
                    System.out.println("dropping evtg");
                }
```

This is giving me an error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Also the normal iteration:

```
          for(IEVEnt event:al){}
```

is giving an error

To be more clear the swtsee a d sdctsee are taken from previous iterations on the arraylist and saved so i can delete if I have the new condition. So is there a way when I detect them to shift them to higher indexes and then I use a reverse iteration?

What to do?

Comment: If you really need to do this, consider `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, or other collections designed for concurrent use. Their iterators are guaranteed not to throw this exception. But they're probably overkill unless you're really using multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove element as discussed by you.

Do not delete while iterating.

- Keep a `Hash` for all the objects you want to `delete`.
- Do a second iteration which delete using `.remove()` if the object is in `Hash`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete if you are using for each style or iterator.

Use normal for loop like following

```
for(int i=0; i<al.size ; i++){
   if(something){
      al.remove(i)  
      i--;
    }

}
```

This will work.

Comment: yes but i want to remove many objects when i find the condition. So if it was in lower indexes i will have the problem

Comment: i-- will do. for example your list has 10 elements(size=10). currently you are in 5th element, so i=4; now you are deleting 2nd element. al.get(i) will return you the next element. (i--, i++, the result would be i)

Comment: Do you mean `for (int i = al.size; i > 0; --i)
   if (something) 
      al.remove (i)  
`

Comment: Ah, yes, now I see. you decrement on deletion. Yes, that works, but you **can** delete with for-each-style iterator, not just directly.

Answer (score 1):

To remove with an Iterator, you collect your stuff in a new Collection, and remove in a final step, for example:

```
    // list := List (1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 9, 6, 5, 7, 8);
List <Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList <Integer> ();       
for (int i : list)
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
        toRemove.add (i);
list.removeAll (toRemove);
```

I can't see how `a1` is connected to your `i`. As long as it isn't iterated over, it should be secure to call those 2 `a1.remove (...)`-ings while iterating.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference [Java Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

your code should work fine commenting the following lines

```
for (Iterator i = al.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
{
    IEvent event =(IEvent) i.next();
   if (nbSendingWTS > 0 || nbSendingCTS > 0)
   {
          // You have got the iterator for the underlying array list(al)
          **only remove the elements through iterator.**   
          i.remove();

          // after remove thru iterator 
          // you are structurally modifiying arraylist directly(al.remove()) 
          // which gives u concurrent modification
          // al.remove(swtsee);  
          // al.remove(sdctsee);
          System.out.println("dropping evtg");
   }
}
```

and the best way to do is

```
 List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
    l.add(new Integer(1));
    l.add(new Integer(2));
    }
    for (Integer i : l)
    {
        if (i.intValue() == 2)
            itemsToRemove.add(i);
    }

    l.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
    System.out.println(l);
```